# Show that short exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to A\to B\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ is split.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

My question is similar to the following two questions: [Exact sequence of abelian groups, special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400768/exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-special-case?rq=1) and [Show $0 \to A\mathop \to B\mathop \to C \to 0$ is split when $C$ is a free Abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095625/show-0-to-a-mathop-to-b-mathop-to-c-to-0-is-split-when-c-is-a-free-abeli), but neither have been answered.

I have an idea of how to do this proof:

Let $0\to A\to B\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of abelian groups with $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to\mathbb{Z}$. I want to use the splitting lemma, which states that if there exists a map $j:\mathbb{Z}\to B$ with $gj=1_{\mathbb{Z}}$, then the sequence is split.

Because this is a short exact sequence, we have that $B/A\cong\mathbb{Z}$. Then because $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, so is $B/A$, and in particular $b+A$ for some $b\in B$ generates all of $B/A$. I then want to use this fact somehow to construct a map from $\mathbb{Z}\to B$ which composes with $g$ to give the identity in $\mathbb{Z}$, but I can't quite figure out the construction.

Comment: Forget about $B/A$ for a moment. To construct a splitting $j : \mathbb{Z} \to B$, first define $j(1)$ by asking yourself "What must $j(1)$ satisfy?" and then choose $j(1)$ satisfying that. Then prove that there is a unique way to extend the map $j : \{1\} \to B$ to a homomorphism $j : \mathbb{Z} \to B$. Then do the same when $C$ is free abelian.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm not sure I follow. $j(1)$ should equal $1_B$ I believe, but I don't know how to extend this without knowing anything about $B$.

Comment: I don't mean "1" as in the additive identity, I mean "1" as in the generator of the group, meaning the $1$ in $\mathbb{Z} = \{...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...\}$.

Comment: I just answered your question on the case where $C$ is free abelian. This solves also this problem.

Comment: Keep in mind, since these are *abelian* groups, the standard notation for the identity element is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $b_0\in B$ whose image in $\Bbb Z$ is $1$, check that $b_0+A$ generates $B/A$ and define $j$ by $j(1) = b_0$. Since $1$ generates $\Bbb Z$, this defines $j$ completely. Since $g(b_0) = 1$, we have $gj(1) = 1$ thus $gj = 1_{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: This is very helpful! So I can say: Consider the element $b_0\in B$ such that $g(b_0)=1_{\mathbb{Z}}$. By property of a short exact sequence, $B/A\cong\mathbb{Z}$. Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, $B/A$ is as well. Then because $g$ preserves order of elements and $g(b_0)$ generates all of $\mathbb{Z}$, $b_0+A$ generates all of $B/A$ as well. Now, define a map $j:\mathbb{Z}\to B$ with $j(1)=b_0$. Then, $g(j(1))=g(b_0)=1$, so by the splitting lemma, this sequence is split.

Comment: I am a bit confused about one part though- if I want to say the sequence is spilt, it definitely makes sense that $b_0+A$ should generate all of $B/A$, but it is not immediately clear to me how this should follow from the fact that $g(b_0)$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$. Specifically, I feel like this should say something about $B$ rather than $B/A$, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: $g$ induces an **isomorphism** $\bar{g}$ from $B/A$ to $\Bbb Z$. Since $g(b_0) = 1$ generates $\Bbb Z$, apply $\bar{g}^{-1}$ to it: this gives $b_0+A$ and this is a generator of $B/A$ since $\bar{g}^{-1}$ is an isomorphism and since $1$ generates $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Everything makes sense to me now.